# Determine all polynomials $P(x)$ with real coefficients for which there exists a positive integer $n$ such that for all $x$,

Tags: functions, polynomials

I have a more general question. When asked to find "all polynomials" or "all functions", are there any standard ways to approach such problems. I have not been able to notice much similarity. I would like any solution/tips you have for the question mentioned below.

Determine all polynomials $P(x)$ with real coefficients for which there exists a positive
integer $n$ such that for all $x$,
$$P(x + \frac{1}{n}) + P(x - \frac{1}{n}) = 2P(x)$$

Comment: You are expected to add your own attempts at answering these problems - it helps others help you.

Comment: Nothing substantial was done. Just tried x=0. Nothing much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are approaches for functional equations that you may want to try, but in this particular case, I would provide the following hints:

1. If $P(x)$ is a polynomial which satisfies that equation for all real $x$, then so is $P'(x)$.
2. Now it is easy to see that any linear polynomial, say $P(x) = ax+b$ would satisfy this, but no quadratic would, and hence no higher order polynomial would.

Comment: Thanks anyway..