# for all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ we have: $P\left(x+\frac1n\right)+P\left(x-\frac1n\right)=2P(x)$

Tags: polynomials

> Determine the polynomial $P\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ for which there exists $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ we have: $$P\left(x+\frac1n\right)+P\left(x-\frac1n\right)=2P(x)$$

---

I found an answer of this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4157009/determine-all-polynomials-px-with-real-coefficients-for-which-there-exists-a?noredirect=1)
There, someone provided a hint that if $P(x)$ is a polynomial which satisfies that equation for all real $x$, then so does $P'(x)$. However I'm not able to understand how that's true. I wrote down the $P(x)$ in the general form and then wrote $P'(x)$ but I'm not able to see how it is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the equality
$$
P\left(x+\frac1n\right)+P\left(x-\frac1n\right)=2P(x).
$$
If you differentiate the LHS, you get $P'\left(x+\frac1n\right)+P'\left(x-\frac1n\right)$ and if you differentiate the RHS, you get $2P'(x)$. Therefore
$$
P'\left(x+\frac1n\right)+P'\left(x-\frac1n\right)=2P'(x).
$$